# Changing material with Geometry Nodes

Tags: animation, materials, geometry-nodes

I've created a ring that changes the material of a pill based on its position.

What I don't understand is why I have to raise the ring so much to change the material of the entire pill.

[image]

I expected that the height of the ring and the material changed at the same speed.

What is wrong in my Geometry Node?

[image]

Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Comment: you did a small mistake here. You compare the *face.position.Z* with the *ring.location* vector (XYZ). But you actually want to compare it with the Z value of location only. So add another *Separate XYZ* node between the *Object Info* and the *Greater Than* math node and use its Z value. That's it :-)

Comment: How easy. Thank you so much Blunder :)